# Почему не получается проверить background у элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня такой код:

```
$(function answersOne () {
   $('form .OneAns .form-group .btn-link').click(function () {
      $('form .OneAns .form-group .btn-link').css('background', 'white')
      $(this).css('background', 'lightgreen');
   });
   $('.OneAns button.btn-danger').click(function() {
      if ($('#OneAnsOne').css('background') == 'lightgreen') {
         alert('Верно')
      } else {
         alert('Неверно')
      }
   })
});
```

При проверке на цвет фона, пишет "Неверно", хотя я уже много раз проверил в `"Инспектор DOM и стилей"`, цвет устанавливается именно для кнопки с классом `btn-link`. В чём проблема?

Comment: выведите в лог `console.log($('#OneAnsOne').css('background'))`

Comment: `form .OneAns .form-group .btn-link` цвет задаете этому селектору, а проверяете у `#OneAnsOne` это точно так должно быть??

Comment: без разметки не скажешь

Answer (score 0):

Вот маленький демонстрасьон, почему ваше условие не работает. Там в background записывается еще много чего, кроме цвета. Во-вторых, именно фоновый цвет записывается в виде `rgb(rr, gg, bb)` — поэтому нужно сравнить с числовым значением

```
$('#OneAnsOne').css('backgroundColor') == rgb(144, 238, 144)
```

а не со словом, соответствующим этому цвету.

(нерабочее демо)

```js
$(function answersOne () {
   $('.btn-link').click(function () {
      $('.btn-link').css('background', '#050');
      $(this).css('background', 'lightgreen');
   });
   
   $('.btn-danger').click(function() {
      console.log($('#OneAnsOne').css('background'));
      if ($('#OneAnsOne').css('background') == 'lightgreen') {
         alert('Верно');
      } else {
         alert('Неверно');
      }
   });
});
```

```css
.btn-link { display: inline-block; background: #123; width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-link" id="OneAnsOne"></div>
<div class="btn-link"></div>
<div class="btn-link"></div>
<div class="btn-link"></div>
<div class="btn-link"></div>

<button class="btn-danger">клик</button>
```

P.s. хорошо бы во всех остальных местах тоже переделать в `background-color`. Так безопаснее... Например если до этого у элемента был `background-image`, а вы меняете его фоновый цвет просто с помощью `background` - то он заодно сотрет и фоновую картинку.

---

http://learn.javascript.ru/ - в 1.4 пункте про `console` - полезная штука. Если лень в браузере каждый раз открывать консоль и смотреть результаты, можно использовать эту песочницу - - https://playcode.io/ (там в углу есть окно для сообщений console)